# How do I extract string a between Wordpress-style shortcodes?

Tags: regex, wordpress, preg-replace, preg-match

This is probably trivial for Regex experts. Sadly, that ain't me.

Given the following string:text:

Here is a paragraph and [callout]this is a test[/callout] of the system.

I want to use preg_match() and/or preg_replace to create the following

```
<div class="callout">this is a test</div>
```

And here is where I am now...

```
$content = 'Here is a paragraph and [callout]this is a test[/callout] of the system.';
$pattern = "/[callout](.*?)[\/callout]/s";
$matches = array();
preg_match($pattern, $content, $matches);
var_dump($match[0]);
```

...Where I get stuck is that the pattern above seems to include the tags, ie.

```
[callout]this is a test[/test]
```

...what am I missing?

TIA,

Comment: did you checked `$matches[1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this regex,

```
\[callout\](.*?)\[\/callout\]
```

It will [capture the group](https://regex101.com/r/vU0aR7/1) `this is a test` from `Here is a paragraph and [callout]this is a test[/callout] of the system`

[Working Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vU0aR7/1)

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the square brackets:

```
$pattern = "~\[callout\](.*?)\[/callout\]~s";
```

And as the [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) reference says:

> If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. `$matches[0]` will contain the text that matched the full pattern, `$matches[1]` will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

You can find the desired text in `$matches[1]`.